# linq to sql not counting all columns

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table called `Game`, which holds 4 columns for player id's. And I also have a table called `Player`. When I try to count all the games in which a player has been in, I only get the players from the first column in the `Game` table.

```
player.Games.Count();
```

I have set up foreign keys for all the tables, and it's showing up correctly in the table designer. From the image below, you can see that it should count from blue1+2 and red1+2, but it only counts from `Blue1`...

[image]

I also tried to create a method to manually select all the games:

```
public int GetPlayerGames(int playerID)
{
    return (from game in db.Games
            where game.Blue1 == playerID
            || game.Blue2 == playerID
            || game.Red1 == playerID
            || game.Red2 == playerID
            select game).Count();
}
```

But when I use it inside a linq query

```
return from player in db.Players
       where GetPlayerGames(player.ID) > 0
       select player;
```

I get this error:
`Method 'Int32 GetPlayerGames(Int32)' has no supported translation to SQL.`

Comment: Looks like Player is a 1 to Many relationship.  In your Game record, is there one record where all player id values are populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using the method above, but just casting it to a list first:

```
return from player in db.Players.ToList()
       where GetPlayerGames(player.ID) > 0
       select player;
```

Comment: Make sure you are aware of the consequences of "just casting it to a list" though. Calling db.Players.ToList() goes to the database and fetches the entire database table into memory, then applies the filtering afterwards, in code. That's probably not what you want: it won't scale well when the number of Players gets large...

Comment: Yup. I know. For now, I'm fairly sure the list won't exceed 20 players. But you're absolutely right, it won't scale well. So until I find a good way to write methods that linq understand, I'll just keep it this way, while keeping in mind that I will have to refactor at a later point.

Answer (score 1):

If you've set up four relationships they'll each have a different name, most likely `Games`, `Games1`, `Games2` and `Games3`. By doing `player.Games.Count()` you're only counting the games associated with the first relationship, you need to add extra counts for the games associated by the other relationships:

```
var allGameCounts = player.Games.Count() + player.Games1.Count() + player.Games2.Count() + player.Games3.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the filtering in sql without loading the whole database, you could do this...

```
from player in db.Players
where player.Games.Any()
  || player.Games1.Any()
  || player.Games2.Any()
  || player.Games3.Any()
select player
```